# css align ul to form

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm doing a live search with ajax. I want to align the form and the ul.
here my form

```
<div align="right">
    <form method="post" action="" id="search" class="kb-search">
        <input type="text" id="kbsearch" name="kbsearch" placeholder="Knowledge Base" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="searchKB"/>
    </form>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
</div>
```

and here my css

```
.kb-search {
    width: 250px;
}
#results {
    text-align:left;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

How can I do this:
[image]

Comment: Please make sure code in your question *actually reproduces the issue*. Current code [does not repro](http://jsfiddle.net/v77KQ/) the issue (even with [fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/v77KQ/1/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent div position to relative.. then to the #results add right: 0.. I think this will do..

Answer (score 2):

**Define your parent** `div` `position:relative;`

```
#results{
    top: 8px;
    left: 2px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jyYmC/)**

Comment: what is that? your demo is not like the picture what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You parent `div` needs to have `position: relative` so that you can position elements inside relevant to it.  So

```
<div align="right" style="position: relative;">
```

Then

```
#results {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px; /* e.g Offset it by the height of the input field */
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**maybe this is your Answer:**

```
 <style>
#kbsearch {
            width: 250px;

        }
        #results{
            text-align:left;
            width: 234px;
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            max-height: 400px;
            overflow: auto;
            margin-top:-5px;
            z-index: 99;
            border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
            border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
</style>
```

and put this in `body` or other place what you like:

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="" id="search" class="kb-search">
        <input type="text" id="kbsearch" name="kbsearch" placeholder="Knowledge Base" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="searchKB"/>
    </form>
    <ul id="results">f</ul>
</div>
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

The best and most reusable way to do this is:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

#results {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
}
```

By setting the results to `top: 100%`  ensures that the results will **always** sit underneath the search box regardless of the height of it.

This is by far the better way, as putting a specific pixel value for `top` is quite brittle and unresuable.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67njq/)